# Blazor - object displayed in a table not updating after changing a value

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am developing a Server-Side Blazor app in which a user inputs excel files with data. The app goes over each excel file, checks if it is valid and creates output files (based on excel file content) for user to download.

There is a table that displays `IEnumerable<IExcelFile>`, a list of objects with following parameters: `FileName`, `FileType`, `Package` (not for display). I would like to call a method that iterates over each `IExcelFile` and take some actions for each excel (check if valid, process). When the method is running I would like `FileType` of each `IExcelFile` to indicate, on which step of the process a particular file is. e.g. When method starts all `IExcelFile`s have a "Queued" `FileType`, when one of `IExcelFile`s is processed it's `FileType` changes to "Processing", when an exception is thrown for one excel file it's `FileType` changes to "Error" and so on.

I am able to change those parameters just before and after running this method but not when the method is running. Below is the code:

Table:

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>FileName</th>
            <th>FileType</th>
            <th style="width: 10px;"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (excelFiles != null && excelFiles.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var excelFile in excelFiles)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@excelFile.FileName</td>
                    <td>@excelFile.FileType.ToString()</td>
                    <td>
                        @if (!IsLoading)
                        {
                            <button class="btn btn-close" @onclick="() => DeleteExcelFile(excelFile)"></button>
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    No files provided
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Processing excel file starts when the user clicks a "Start" button:

```html
@if (!IsLoading)
{
    <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="formFileMultiple" class="form-label">Select excel files from your drive</label>
    @for (int i = 0; i < numberOfInputFiles; i++)
    {
        <InputFile @key="i" OnChange="UploadExcelFiles" multiple style="@GetInputFileStyle(i)" class="form-control" type="file" id="formFileMultiple"></InputFile>
    }
    </div>

    @if (IsDownloadAvailable)
    {
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @onclick="DownloadDubCards">Download</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ClearExcelFileList">Clear</button> 
    }
    else
    {
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="GenerateDubCards">Start</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ClearExcelFileList">Clear</button> 
    }
       
}
else
{
    <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status" style="left: 50%; position: absolute; width: 3rem; height: 3rem;">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
    </div>
}
```

And the method that is processing the excel files:

```
private void GenerateDubCards()
{
    foreach (var excelFile in excelFiles)
    {
        excelFile.FileType = IExcelFile.Type.Queued;
    }
    foreach (var excelFile in excelFiles)
    {
        try
        {
            excelFile.FileType = IExcelFile.Type.Processing;
            List<IDubCardSet> tempDubCardSets = dubCardGenerator.CalculateDubCardSetsFromExcelFile(excelFile);
            dubCardSets = dubCardGenerator.AddDubCardSets(tempDubCardSets);
            foreach (var dubCardSet in dubCardSets.Where(dcs => dcs.DubCards.Count == 0))
            {
                dubCardGenerator.CreateDubCards(dubCardSet);
            }
            excelFile.FileType = IExcelFile.Type.Completed;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            excelFile.FileType = IExcelFile.Type.Error;
            AppLogger.GetInstance().Info(ex.Message);
            Modal.Open("Something went wrong!", ex.Message);
        }
    }
    IsDownloadAvailable = true;
}
```

So basically after this method runs I just see all excel files have a `FileType` "Complete", but when the method runs I see no other values in between (even when debugging step by step).

Additional context that I hope is irrelevant for this issue:

1. This is a child component but no parameters are passed from the parent to child nor are any parameters from child shared with or dependent on parent.
2. This components has other methods that use `StateHasChanged()` like deleting or adding list elements that work properly.

I tried changing method from `private void` to `async Task`, call `StateHasChanged()` anywhere but with no success. I tried pretty much any related solutions on Stack Overflow, but it didn't work. Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Try calling `StateHasChanged()` in your `@code { ... }` block after processing has finished.

Comment: I tried putting StateHasChanged() after each  excelFile.FileType = IExcelFile.Type.XXX; but with no result. I have also tried making this method an async Task and then calling StateHasChanged() but with same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified your code into a single page which I believe demonstrates what you're trying to achieve.  It demonstrates the principles of using async coding and using `StateHasChanged` to drive re-renders.  The key bit is that the backend process that gets the data has to be a yielding async process for this to work properly.  The Renderer needs thread time to update the UI.  Blocking processes stop that happening.

```
@page "/"
<h3>Async File Processing</h3>
<div class=m-2>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=GenerateDubCards>Process</button>
</div>

@foreach(var file in excelFiles)
{
    <div class="m-2 p-2 @GetCss(file)">@file.Name : @file.State</div>
}

@code {
    private List<ExcelFile> excelFiles = new() { new ExcelFile { Name="UK"}, new ExcelFile { Name="Spain"}, new ExcelFile { Name="Portugal"}, new ExcelFile { Name="Australia"}};

    private string GetCss(ExcelFile file)
    => file.State switch
    {
        FileState.Complete => "bg-success text-white",
        FileState.Processing => "bg-warning text-white",
        FileState.Error => "bg-danger text-white",
        _ => "bg-primary text-white"
    };

    private async  Task GenerateDubCards()
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach(var file in excelFiles)
        {
            tasks.Add(ProcessAFile(file));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }

    private async Task ProcessAFile(ExcelFile file)
    {
        file.State = FileState.Processing;
        StateHasChanged();
        // emulate the file work with a variable length Task Delay
        await Task.Delay(Random.Shared.Next(5000));
        file.State = FileState.Complete;
        if (file.Name.StartsWith("S"))
            file.State = FileState.Error;

        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public class ExcelFile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public FileState State { get; set; } = FileState.None;
    }

    public enum FileState
    {
        None,
        Processing,
        Complete,
        Error
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Solution you provided works, and explains the relation between `async Task` and `StateHasChanged()`. I was able to solve my problem, and I understand this issue a little better. It still seems weird that this method won't work if I delete the line `await Task.Delay(Random.Shared.Next(5000));`. As I understand from VS comments, without that await the Task will run as sync not async, therefore StateHasChanged() will have no effect. Another issue I can't figure out is if I use the await... line at the end of my method, Task will run as async, but states wont update.

Comment: Everything revolves around yielding.  Calling `StateHasChanged` doesn't in itself re-render the component, it just places the render fragment that represents the component onto the Render Queue.  If a Task based method yields and everything behind it yields, then the Renderer gets some thread time and can service it's Render queue.  If it's all sync code then you can call `StateHasChanged` as many times as you like, nothing will happen.  FYI, `StateHasChanged` has a mechanism to recognise if it already has a render fragment stacked in the queue and doesn't add another.

Comment: Could you also please mark the question as answered if you're happy with my answer.